# How do I close an automatically opened window in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

This is probably a very naive Emacs question - I'm new to it.

When I'm evaluating a lisp expression, if there's an error the debugger automatically comes up in another window. If I have *scratch* and *info* open (the former for trying out lisp and the latter for reading about it), then the debugger opens up in the window that *info* was in. At the moment, I have to switch to that window, then change it back to *info*, before returning to *scratch*. (The same thing happens if I do C-x C-b for a list of buffers.) I'm guessing there has to be a way to just close that window without this long sequence of commands. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: maybe ask this over at SuperUser?

Comment: I did contemplate that... It's tricky deciding. Is it alright to cross-post? (I guess I should be asking that at meta :P)

Comment: Since most questions regarding Emacs usually involve writing a little bit of elisp, they seem to be best answered here.  :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

At least here on my emacs (22.3), when the debugger pops up, its window becomes the active one. There, pressing <kbd>q</kbd> just quits the debugger, if that's what you want. At that point, it also gets out of recursive editing.

Comment: Yep, that works! It doesn't solve the case of the persistent buffer list though, but maybe that's another question...

Comment: "q" is a fairly common exit mechanism for lots of pop up windows.  Works with calc, calendar, debuggers, dired and lots of others that aren't built-in, like browse-kill-ring.  It works with the persistent buffer list as well, though you have to switch to the buffer list first.  If you have a particular working window configuration, you can store it with C-x r w <some key> and then jump back to it with C-x r j <same letter> at any time.

Comment: I was playing around with 24.5, can confirm the 'q' solution. However, if 'q' fails you in any instance, `C-x 0` will also close the focused window.

Answer (score 21):

I'm usually using the `delete-other-windows` command. `C-x 1`.

It's so regullar, that I rebinded to F4.

Official docs: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Change-Window.html#Change-Window

HTH

Answer (score 21):

From what I understand, you want to close the buffer in the other window without moving your cursor from the current window.

I don't any existing function does that, so I rolled my own.

```
(defun other-window-kill-buffer ()
  "Kill the buffer in the other window"
  (interactive)
  ;; Window selection is used because point goes to a different window
  ;; if more than 2 windows are present
  (let ((win-curr (selected-window))
        (win-other (next-window)))
    (select-window win-other)
    (kill-this-buffer)
    (select-window win-curr)))
```

You can bind it to something like "C-x K" or some other somewhat difficult-to-press key so you won't press it by mistake.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x K") 'other-window-kill-buffer)
```

I use this a LOT! (for Help buffers, Compilation buffers, Grep buffers, and just plain old buffers I want to close now, without moving the point)

Answer (score 7):

Using [winner mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WinnerMode), you can use the keybinding C-C left arrow to return to the previous window configuration.  Of course, this doesn't actually kill the new buffer, but it does hide it.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for <kbd>C-x 4 C-o</kbd>, which displays a buffer in the "other" window without switching to it.

As mentioned above, in the case of the backtrace buffer you probably want to exit from it with <kbd>q</kbd>, to get out of the recursive edit.

Comment: It chooses as default the previous buffer in that window so you can just hit return. Nice and easy. Your `C-x 4 C-o` is bound to `display-buffer` and its documentation text says "Display BUFFER-OR-NAME in some window, without selecting it." So it will often choose the just-used help window See also other answer here: `C-x 4 b` which is bound to `switch-to-buffer-other-window` which does almost the exactly same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `popwin-mode`. It is really good about closing windows automatically.

I want to describe how mechanism work|

You open `undo-tree-visualize` than you find your correct branch, after that when you change your active window which has cursor via `switch-window` `undo-tree` related buffer will close other window automatically.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a window management package.  Store your "preferred" window arrangement, and after the debugger/buffer window pops up and you're done with it, revert to your preferred arrangement.

There are a bunch of packages to choose from, see: [switching window configurations](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryWindows#toc4) on the wiki.

Additionally, you might want to figure out the actions you commonly do that trigger the extra (unwanted) window popping up, and use that to trigger saving your window configuration just before the window pops up.

If you want to roll your own (it's pretty easy), you can just save off the window configuration, and restore it like so:

```
(setq the-window-configuration-i-want (current-window-configuration))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f7>") 
       (lambda () (interactive) 
            (set-window-configuration the-window-configuration-i-want)))
```

The trick is figuring out where to put the setting of `the-window-configuration-i-want`.

Answer (score 0):

If emacs *selects* your new buffer in its window, as it apparently does for the debugger, at least in some versions of emas, then `q` does work.

However for `*Help*` or `*Arpopos*` or `*Occur*` or `*Grep*` or similar buffers opened in an *un*selected window over another buffer you want back, `C-x 4 b` may help you. (Very similar to @legoscia's answered Jul 31, 2009 at 17:36)

`C-x 4 b` is by default bound to `switch-to-buffer-other-window` and defaults to the previous buffer in that window so you can easily get it back. Or `M-p` can cycle through other previous buffers.

Similar question: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58717/how-to-close-help-buffer-without-moving-to-it/

Answer (score -1):

Thanks go to @spk for a nice function. I merely modified it to also close the window too and bound it to the already nice set of window control functions found in evil-windows (via "C-w"):

```
(use-package evil
  :bind (:map evil-window-map ("O" . delete-most-recent-window))
  :preface
  (defun delete-most-recent-window ()
    "Kill the buffer in the most recent window."
    (interactive)
    ;; Window selection is used because point goes to a different window
    ;; if more than 2 windows are present
    (let ((win-curr (selected-window))
          (win-other (next-window)))
      (select-window win-other)
      (kill-this-buffer)   
      (delete-window)   ; <-- Added this
      (select-window win-curr))))
```